# VLC and VLCJ licenses

Tags: licensing, gpl, license-compatibility, gpl-3, lgpl

I'm confused about the licenses GPL and LGPL.
I see that VLC is released under LGPL license since sept 2011: https://www.videolan.org/press/lgpl.html.  But VLCJ, which is a Java wrapper on top of VLC, is released under the GPL license that is more restrictive (stronger copyleft).

Is that allowed?

So if yet another library uses VLCJ, it also can be released under GPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is allowed. See the LGPL v2.1, section 3:

> 3. You may opt to apply the terms of the ordinary GNU General Public License instead of this License to a given copy of the Library. To do this, you must alter all the notices that refer to this License, so that they refer to the ordinary GNU General Public License, version 2, instead of to this License. (If a newer version than version 2 of the ordinary GNU General Public License has appeared, then you can specify that version instead if you wish.) Do not make any other change in these notices.
>
> Once this change is made in a given copy, it is irreversible for that copy, so the ordinary GNU General Public License applies to all subsequent copies and derivative works made from that copy.
>
> This option is useful when you wish to copy part of the code of the Library into a program that is not a library.

It is best to understand the LGPL as “GPL + extra permissions”. The LGPL v3 makes this explicit. The GPL does not allow more restrictions to be added.